# change combined classed variable in c++

Tags: c++, class, combinations

I have a class called `Factory` with a variable named `balance`. I made an object from it called `f`. In the other hand I have a class called `Medicine` that must change `balance` in `f`. I made two object of `Medicine` named `med1` and `med2`.

`med1` adds `f`'s `balance` by 10. `med2` adds `f` `balance` by 5. But these changes don't add with each other in `f`.
It seems every `Medicine` object have its own copy of `f`.

Is there any way to save these changes in `f`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Factory
{
public:
    Factory() {};
    void addbalance(int x)
    {
        balance += x;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout << balance;
    }
private:
    int balance = 0;
};

class Medicine
{
public:
    Medicine() {};
    Medicine(Factory f)
    {
        fact = f;
    }
    void addBalance(int x)
    {
        fact.addbalance(x);
    }
    void show()
    {
        fact.show();
    }
private:
    Factory fact;
};

int main()
{
    Factory f;
    Medicine medi1(f), medi2(f);

    medi1.addBalance(10);
    medi2.addBalance(5);
    f.show(); // I want here to show 15, not 0.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using references.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Factory
{
public:
    Factory() {};
    void addbalance(int x)
    {
        bal += x;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout << bal;
    }
private:
    int bal = 0;
};

class Medicine
{
public:
    // now cannot be initialized without a Factory
    //Medicine() {};
    Medicine(Factory& f) : fact(f) // add & and initialize via member initialization list
    {
    }
    void addBalance(int x)
    {
        fact.addbalance(x);
    }
    void show()
    {
        fact.show();
    }
private:
    Factory& fact; // add &
};

int main()
{
    Factory f;
    Medicine medi1(f), medi2(f);

    medi1.addBalance(10);
    medi2.addBalance(5);
    f.show(); // I want here to show 15, not 0.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the variable balance a static variable and then call it with class name and :: operator

Comment: It is dangerous to use static variables for that use. If you later want to use different factories each with its own set of Medecine objects, it will be impossible with static variables, while using references would be fine.